# How to supress warnings from console

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, ddl

I'm creating some functions in plpgsql, using some temp tables, but the console returns warning about that tables, it's possible to hide them?

I'm opperating the tables with

> CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS old_competencegroup (id integer, autoevaluation bool, category integer, sucess varchar) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
> TRUNCATE evaluations_to_consolidate;
> INSERT INTO evaluations_to_consolidate

And the console returns a lot of

> [2020-12-10 18:47:17] [42P07] relation "old_competencegroup" already exists, skipping

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run statement `SET client_min_messages TO WARNING;`

You can store this statement in `~/.psqlrc` file.